# Equivalent of xsum for pySCIPOpt

Tags: python, optimization, scip

What is the equivalent of `xsum` from python Mip in pySCIPOpt to summarize arrays of variables in constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `quicksum` for that purpose. I suggest you look at some of the examples for PySCIPopt, e.g., [this one](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/examples/finished/gcp.py)